# Getting CORS policy error while using spring boot with angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cors

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.2 , I have spring-starter-web and spring-data-jpa in my project, Im' not using Spring Security for the moment.
I created RestControllers and added @CrossOrigin annotation to them, and tried this code to enable CORS for my angular app

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {

    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")..allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET","POST","DELETE","PATCH","OPTIONS");
                }
            }
        };

}
```

But still getting CORS Error from my angular app

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
Create a new Class called *CorsConfiguration* or any name

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

private static final String HTTP_LOCALHOST_4200 = "http://localhost:4200";
private static final String GET = "GET";
private static final String POST = "POST";
private static final String PUT = "PUT";
private static final String DELETE = "DELETE";
private static final String HEAD = "HEAD";

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(
                    HTTP_LOCALHOST_4200).allowedMethods(GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, 
HEAD).allowCredentials(true);
}
}
```